# Java: Is it possible to override minimum window width set by the OS?

Tags: java, operating-system, jframe, minimum-size

I am writing a small program that requires a JFrame to decrease in width until it reaches 0. However, I believe the operating system prevents windows from getting skinnier than a certain width to prevent from obstructing the buttons on the top left (I have observed this on both Windows 10 and OS X). Is there a way to override or prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's set by the OS. If you want to make it appear that the `JFrame` goes away, just set it's `visible` to false after a certain width.

```
if(frame.width < someNumber) {
    frame.setVisible(false);
}
```